# Visualization mixing in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to train global land cover dataset as training for classification. When I try to visualize final classified map, its mixing as colors are not coming good. Is there any way to fix min max range while its mixing probably 95 band. Or is there way to use Map band from global cover in classified final map as color palette?

This is the script

```
// Define a region of interest.
// Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var getFactorImg = function(factorNames) {
    var factorList = image.toDictionary().select(factorNames).values();
    return ee.Image.constant(factorList);
  };
  var scaleImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var offsetImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scaleImg).add(offsetImg);

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}

// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
var input = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
    .map(prepSrL8)
    .median()
    .setDefaultProjection('EPSG:4326', null, 30)
    .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']);

// Use MODIS land cover, IGBP classification, for training.
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/WorldCover/v100').first()
    .select('Map');

// Sample the input imagery to get a FeatureCollection of training data.
var training = input.addBands(modis).sample({
  region: roi,
  numPixels: 5000,
  seed: 0
});

// Make a Random Forest classifier and train it.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10)
    .train({
      features: training,
      classProperty: 'Map',
      inputProperties: ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
    });

// Classify the input imagery.
var classified = input.classify(classifier);

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());

// Sample the input with a different random seed to get validation data.
var validation = input.addBands(modis).sample({
  region: roi,
  numPixels: 5000,
  seed: 1
  // Filter the result to get rid of any null pixels.
}).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(input.bandNames()));

// Classify the validation data.
var validated = validation.classify(classifier);

// Get a confusion matrix representing expected accuracy.
// var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('Map', 'classification');
// print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
// print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());

// Define a palette for the IGBP classification.
var igbpPalette = [
  '006400', 
  'ffbb22', 
  'ffff4c', 
  'f096ff', 
  'fa0000', 
  'b4b4b4', 
  'f0f0f0', 
  '0064c8', 
  '0096a0', 
  '00cf75', 
  'fae6a0' ];

// Display the input and the classification.
Map.addLayer(input.clip(roi),
             {bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'], min: 0, max: 0.25},
             'landsat');
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(roi),
             {palette: igbpPalette, min: 10, max: 100},
             'classification 2020');
             
var sample = input.addBands(modis).sample({
  numPixels: 5000,
  seed: 0
});

// The randomColumn() method will add a column of uniform random
// numbers in a column named 'random' by default.
sample = sample.randomColumn();

var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% testing.
var training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var validation = sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));

// Sample the input imagery to get a FeatureCollection of training data.
var sample = input.addBands(modis).sample({
  region: roi,
  numPixels: 5000,
  seed: 0,
  geometries: true,
  tileScale: 16
});

// The randomColumn() method will add a column of uniform random
// numbers in a column named 'random' by default.
sample = sample.randomColumn();

var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% testing.
var training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
print(training.size());
var validation = sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));

// Spatial join.
var distFilter = ee.Filter.withinDistance({
  distance: 1000,
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
});

var join = ee.Join.inverted();

// Apply the join.
training = join.apply(training, validation, distFilter);
print(training.size());
```

The final script link is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a06cb6b4c6a1d35e8c653d06b087295c